# Chart.js Fill color at null line and null points Tooltip

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have the following code. The line is blue and if data is `null`, a red line is drawn. This already works quite well.
But how do I add a corresponding fill color (blue for blue and red for red)?
And how do I make it so that the tooltip points are set despite `null`?
I have already tried to add `fill: true,` and `backgroundColor: '#blue',` in the `datasets` but it did not bring the desired result.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    plugins: [{
        beforeDraw: chart => {
            var ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
            ctx.save();
            let xAxis = chart.scales['x-axis-0'];
            let yAxis = chart.scales['y-axis-0'];
            let dataset = chart.data.datasets[0];
            var valueFrom = null;
            var valueFromIndex = 0;
            var xFrom = null;
            let yFrom = null;
            ctx.strokeStyle = dataset.borderColor;
            ctx.fillStyle = dataset.backgroundColor;
            ctx.label = dataset.label;
            dataset.data.forEach((value, index) => {
            if (value != null) {
                var x = xAxis.getPixelForTick(index);
                var y = yAxis.getPixelForValue(value);
                if (valueFrom != null) {
                    ctx.lineWidth = dataset.borderWidth;
                    if (index - valueFromIndex > 1) {
                        ctx.setLineDash([]);
                        ctx.strokeStyle = '#ff0000';
                    } else {
                        ctx.setLineDash([]);
                        ctx.strokeStyle = '#3d93a8';
                    }
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.moveTo(xFrom, yFrom);
                    ctx.lineTo(x, y);
                    ctx.stroke();
                }
                valueFrom = value;
                valueFromIndex = index;
                xFrom = x;
                yFrom = y;
            }
        });
        ctx.restore();
        }
    }],
    data: {
        labels: ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8"],
        datasets: [{
            label: "Number",
            data: [20,15,null,18,21,null,8,16],
            pointBackgroundColor: '#000000',
            pointRadius: 0.0,
            pointHoverRadius: 0.0,
            pointStyle: 'rectRounded',
            borderColor: '#3d93a8',
            lineTension: 0.6,
            borderWidth: 2.5,
            showLine: false,
        }]
    },
    options: {
        title: {
            display: true,
            fontStyle: 'bold',
            fontSize: '20',
            fontColor: '#000',
            position: 'top',
            lineHeight: 1.0,
            text: 'Description',
        },
        legend: {
            display: false,
            position: "butt",
            labels: {}
        },  
        tooltips: {
            enabled: true,
            mode: 'index',
            intersect: false,
            xPadding: 15,
            bodySpacing: 0,
            cornerRadius: 10,
            titleMarginBottom: 5,
            position: 'nearest',
            titleAlign: 'center',
        },  
        animation: {
            duration: 0
        },
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                stacked: true,
                barThickness: 'flex',
                maxBarThickness: 100,
                gridLines: {
                display:false
            },
            ticks: {
                autoSkip: true,
                maxTicksLimit: 24
            },
        }],
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true,
            }
        }]
    },
    chartArea: {
        backgroundColor: '#e8e8e8'
    }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="auto" height="100%"></canvas>
```

Comment: What do you mean by fill color? Is that similar to the area chart?

Comment: With fill color I mean the color the diagram is filled with. In [this example](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/18382796/47793818-0f91cd80-dd17-11e8-98f8-99d7f64d218a.png) it is for example green and red.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of drawing the lines within the [`beforeDraw`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html#plugin-core-api) hook, you can compute and define the `borderColor` and `backgroundColor` of the `dataset` inside the `afterLayout` hook using [`CanvasRenderingContext2D.createLinearGradient()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/createLinearGradient). This has the advantage that the `lineTension` option will also be considered and you'll obtain a nice looking Bezier curve.

To make it work, you'll also have to define [`spanGaps: true`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html#line-styling) on the `dataset`. This instructs Chart.js to draw lines between points, even if there are `null` values in between.

```
afterLayout: chart => {
  let ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
  ctx.save();
  let xAxis = chart.scales['x-axis-0'];
  let borderGradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(xAxis.left, 0, xAxis.right, 0);
  let bgGradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(xAxis.left, 0, xAxis.right, 0);
  let dataset = chart.data.datasets[0];
  dataset.data.forEach((value, index) => {
    if (index > 0) { 
      let valueFrom = dataset.data[index - 1];
      let valueTo = dataset.data[index + 1]; 
      let xFrom = xAxis.getPixelForValue(valueFrom);
      let xTo = xAxis.getPixelForTick(index);         
      let offset = 1 / (xAxis.right - xAxis.left) * (xTo - xAxis.left);         
      borderGradient.addColorStop(offset, valueFrom == null || value == null ? '#ff0000' : '#3d93a8'); 
      borderGradient.addColorStop(offset, value == null || valueTo == null ? '#ff0000' : '#3d93a8');
      bgGradient.addColorStop(offset, valueFrom == null || value == null ? 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)' : 'rgba(61, 147, 168, 0.5)'); 
      bgGradient.addColorStop(offset, value == null || valueTo == null ? 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)' : 'rgba(61, 147, 168, 0.5)'); 
    }
  });            
  dataset.borderColor = borderGradient;
  dataset.backgroundColor = bgGradient;
  ctx.restore();
}
```

Please take a look at your amended and runnable code below:

```js
new Chart('canvas', {
  type: 'line',
  plugins: [{
    afterLayout: chart => {
      let ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
      ctx.save();
      let xAxis = chart.scales['x-axis-0'];
      let borderGradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(xAxis.left, 0, xAxis.right, 0);
      let bgGradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(xAxis.left, 0, xAxis.right, 0);
      let dataset = chart.data.datasets[0];
      dataset.data.forEach((value, index) => {
        if (index > 0) { 
          let valueFrom = dataset.data[index - 1];
          let valueTo = dataset.data[index + 1]; 
          let xFrom = xAxis.getPixelForValue(valueFrom);
          let xTo = xAxis.getPixelForTick(index);         
          let offset = 1 / (xAxis.right - xAxis.left) * (xTo - xAxis.left);         
          borderGradient.addColorStop(offset, valueFrom == null || value == null ? '#ff0000' : '#3d93a8'); 
          borderGradient.addColorStop(offset, value == null || valueTo == null ? '#ff0000' : '#3d93a8');
          bgGradient.addColorStop(offset, valueFrom == null || value == null ? 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)' : 'rgba(61, 147, 168, 0.5)'); 
          bgGradient.addColorStop(offset, value == null || valueTo == null ? 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)' : 'rgba(61, 147, 168, 0.5)'); 
        }
      });            
      dataset.borderColor = borderGradient;
      dataset.backgroundColor = bgGradient;
      ctx.restore();
    }
  }],
  data: {
    labels: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"],
    datasets: [{
      label: "Number",
      data: [20, 15, null, 18, 21, null, 8, 16],
      pointRadius: 0.0,
      pointHoverRadius: 0.0,
      lineTension: 0.6,
      borderWidth: 2.5,
      spanGaps: true
    }]
  },
  options: {
    title: {
      display: true,
      fontStyle: 'bold',
      fontSize: '20',
      fontColor: '#000',
      position: 'top',
      lineHeight: 1.0,
      text: 'Description',
    },
    legend: {
      display: false,
      position: "butt",
      labels: {}
    },
    tooltips: {
      enabled: true,
      mode: 'index',
      intersect: false,
      xPadding: 15,
      bodySpacing: 0,
      cornerRadius: 10,
      titleMarginBottom: 5,
      position: 'nearest',
      titleAlign: 'center',
    },
    animation: {
      duration: 0
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        stacked: true,
        barThickness: 'flex',
        maxBarThickness: 100,
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        },
        ticks: {
          autoSkip: true,
          maxTicksLimit: 24
        },
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="auto" height="100%"></canvas>
```